# Monitoring Windows system Read/Write operations by process?

Tags: c#, c++, c, powershell, io

I have been searching through the `System.Diagnostics` namespace looking for a way to monitor the read and write operations done by different processes without any luck.

Does anyone know the classes or interfaces used to get this information? I tried Process class, Event Trace classes, ect and haven't found anything. There have been a few posts on SO about this but none had concrete answers or the post was from over 5 years ago. I am doing this on Win7/Win8.

I basically need to track the total bits Read by a Process from a specific file.

I want to create either a C/C#/C++ application to do this or, if there is a way, directly get the information into a PowerShell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI for that, for example for the process Notepad.exe you can use :

```
Get-WmiObject -Class "WIN32_Process" -Filter "name='notepad.exe'"
```

Then have a look to :

```
ReadOperationCount
ReadTransferCount 
WriteOperationCount
WriteTransferCount
```

You can also access WMI with C#.

Comment: Oh that's cool I didn't realize you can get Total Read transfer amount. Any idea on if I can be more specific by viewing bytes read of a specific file?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find the Filemon tools from SysInternals. They offered the source for download back then, but it was removed. Might be that you can still find it via google.

Basically this was done with a driver, so you would have to implement this as a device driver and use a filter driver on top of the file system. It was for NT/XP, but the basic idea should still work.

It's not exactly trivial though, so I don't know if this is really what you want to do.

I don't see a way to do this from user space, as this would be a big security risk if this can be easily done.